# Babel won't ignore my module regex

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, babeljs

I'm using Mocha to run tests on my React components, so I need Babel in my Mocha bootstrap to transpile the jsx requires.  In my bootstrap.js I start with

```
global.babel = require("babel/register")({
    ignore: [/node_modules/, '**/scss*', /sinon/, /foo/]
});
```

According to the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/), ignore accepts "A glob, regex, or mixed array of both"  But its weird because the `/node_modules/, /sinon/` regexes work, but the `**/scss*` and `/foo/` don't.

For example, here's the top of the component that fails the require:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Link = Router.Link;
var foo = require('foo');
var StyleSheet = require('../../scss/core/Linker');
```

Fails with:

```
  1) app/core/Linker.jsx "before each" hook:
     Error: Cannot find module 'foo'
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/core/Linker.jsx:4:11)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/app/helpers/linker-test.js:10:23)
```

I start the tests like so:

`mocha test --recursive --reporter spec --timeout 30000`

Am I doing it wrong, or losing the babel ignore by the time the required component test is loaded up?

Comment: Does it work if you do it with a regex instead of a glob? https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1912

Comment: nope.  tried a regex too ```/scss/ig```

Comment: Sorry I think I misread this before. What are you expecting `ignore` to do exactly? If it's saying it can't find the module, that has nothing to do with Babel, it means your paths or modules aren't in the right place. And what is `Linker` in this case? `ignore` stops files from being transpiled, it doesn't stop node from trying to load them.

Comment: oh, that's good to know.  I thought all requires would go through babel after babel/register.  Linker is actually a scss partial, so makes sense that node doesn't find it.  Its usually transpiled by webpack, so not a problem.  But tests are node/mocha so they expect a module.export. Any way to ignore node requires via regex?

Comment: Not really, if you're using non-standard path behavior in webpack, you'd probably have to a "test" package for all your code via webpack then run that or something.